# How does angular keep track of bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

How does angular js keep track of the position of the binding in the DOM ? Once they have been replaced with content I can't see how you could find the binding again. Example:

{{address.line1}}

is replaced with

123  Fake Street

if the address object is changed, how does angular know where the {{address.line1}} binding used to be?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Angular implemented this, but a wild guess would be that a copy of the original inner html is stored in a closure during initialization (either in raw form or some inner Angular representation of the same).